# <Link> in Helper method gives "Element link cannot be nested within element 'link'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a Helper method in MVC3 Razor project as(Helpers.cshtml)

```
   @helper Link(string fileName, UrlHelper url){
        <link href="@url.Content("~/Content/" + fileName)" 
              rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   }
```

But i get a warning tooltip "Element link cannot be nested within element 'link'".

I found similar type of question on Asp.net 
[Error when using link href inside my ContentPlaceHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722588/error-when-using-link-href-inside-my-contentplaceholder)

Do we have a solution for this.

Comment: Is this a runtime error or just something that shows up in the designer?

Comment: This just shows up in the designer.

Comment: It's possible that the design-time cannot handle certain more advanced scenarios.

Comment: Does this work as intended at runtime in the browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that you should only have `<link>` tags in the `<head>` and not the `<body>`. **The tooling is unable to confirm from where you'll call this helper**, so it barks.

You can verify that this is what's going on by temporarily wrapping the helper in a valid skeleton of markup as below. The warning should go away. You can then confirm the negative case by changing `link` to some made-up tag like `foo`, or by removing the `title`, and watch those errors then appear. You should then be comfortable that **as long as you only call your helper from inside `<head>` sections, your resulting `link` markup is ok.**

```
<html>
<head>
    @helper Link(string fileName, UrlHelper url){
        <link href="@url.Content("~/Content/" + fileName)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   }
   <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```